# Does kafka-client 0.8.2.1 support ssl

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have kafka broker with SSL configured with the version 0.10.2.1, but we need to write producer using Kafka client 0.8.2.1. Does this client version support SSL security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this client version support SSL security?

No. SSL was introduced in 0.9+ version.

> but we need to write producer using Kafka client 0.8.2.1

That is a questionable practice. If I were you, I would try to keep my clients as close as possible to the brokers, irrespective of whether you want SSL or not. Especially kafka, I have had my hands burnt couple of times because of the broker-client compatibility issues.

Answer (score 1):

No. Kafka 0.8.2.1 does not support SSL. SSL was added in 0.9.

You should consider upgrading your clients if you can as there are many new features, enhancements and security improvements since the March 11, 2015 release of 0.8.2.1

The current release (as of September 2017) is 0.11.0.1 and Kafka 1.0 is scheduled for release next month in October.

Comment: If this answered your question, please accept it, that will help fellow SO users. @Sandesh